# connectNative disconnects by itself in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I did write a chrome extension. My content script send some data to by `background.js`. And my `background.js` shell forward this data to a local C++ app. 
Now what happens is, my `background.js` can connect to the local app and send data once. But then, the connection is lost as the disconnect event occurs and a second send request fails. Reading the documentation of connectNative it says, connection is closed, if the `disconnect` is called or *"when the page containing the port is unloaded"*. I don't have the disconnect at all in my code and the `background.js` should not be unloaded as according documentation the livetime of `background.js` is as long as livetime of the extension. 
With my code, the Test 1 and Test 2 arrive once in the target file `Test.txt` but send it a second time fails, as connection is lost in between.

Here the code.

background.js:

```
var port = null;
var firstTime;

function onNativeMessage(message) {
    console.log("Native Message received: " + message);
}

function onDisconnected() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
    //port = null;
}

function connect() {
    console.log("Connect");
    //port = chrome.extension.connectNative('chromeinterface');
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('chromeinterface');
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(data, sender) {
    if(firstTime !== 'xdefined') {
        firstTime = 'xdefined';
        connect();
    }

    port.postMessage("Test 1");
    port.postMessage("Test 2");
    console.log("Send");
}
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test native messaging",

  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["contentscript.js"]
   }
  ],

  "permissions": ["tabs", "nativeMessaging", "<all_urls>"],

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

chromeinterface.json:

```
{
 "name": "chromeinterface",
 "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
 "path": "chrome_interface",
 "type": "stdio",
 "allowed_origins": [
   "chrome-extension://abc.../"
 ]
}
```

chrome_interface.cpp:

```
...
using namespace std;

void StoreData(string data)
{
   ofstream File;
   File.open("Test.txt", ios_base::out|ios_base::app);
   if (File.is_open())
   {
      File << data;
      File.close();
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf ); 
    unsigned int a, c, i, t=0;
    std::string inp;  
    bool bCommunicationEnds = false;

    StoreData("Start " + inp + "\n");
    cout << "Start" << endl;

    do {

        inp="";
        t=0;
        // Sum the first 4 chars from stdin (the length of the message passed).
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            t += getchar();
        }

        // Loop getchar to pull in the message until we reach the total
        //  length provided.
        for (i=0; i < t; i++) {
            c = getchar();
            if(c == EOF)
            {
                bCommunicationEnds = true;
                i = t;
            }
            else
            {
                inp += c;
            }
        }
        StoreData("Received " + inp + "\n");

        if(!bCommunicationEnds)
        {
            //Collect the length of the message
            unsigned int len = inp.length();
            //// We need to send the 4 btyes of length information
            std::cout << char(((len>>0) & 0xFF))
                << char(((len>>8) & 0xFF))
                << char(((len>>16) & 0xFF))
                << char(((len>>24) & 0xFF));
            //// Now we can output our message
            std::cout << inp;
        }
    }while(!bCommunicationEnds);

    StoreData("Com end\n");

    return 0;
}
```

console.log:

```
Connect
Send
Disconnected
Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `cout << "Start" << endl;` from your code. Native messaging communicates via stdin and stdout. If you insert any other junk in stdout, then the protocol is violated and Chrome will terminate the native application.

Besides that, the following does not really look like "read 4 chars", but "read 3 chars".

```cpp
    // Sum the first 4 chars from stdin (the length of the message passed).
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        t += getchar();
    }
```

Even after changing `i <= 2` to `i < 4`, this will only work for messages up to 255 bytes because you're summing the individual bytes instead of interpreting the four bytes as an integer. I suggest to replace the previous snippet with:

```cpp
    unsigned int t;
    std::cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
```

Start Chrome from the terminal and look in the standard output within the terminal to get more useful errors to debug native applications.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did change that due to a different reason and forgot afterwards. But also with <= 3 it did not work. Does a not correct reading of the input stream result into a disconnect? I would guess, that the Stdio-Buffer should be big enoth to keep the few bytes I'm sending. Anyhow I will try again and especially I will try with starting from the command line to see the errors, that a good tip!

Comment: I did test is with starting from the console and got the following message: `ERROR:native_message_process_host.cc(322)] Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 1819042115 bytes long.` I did guess, it is a problem with `port.postMessage("Test");` and changed it to `port.postMessage({ text: "Test" });` but still the same error message.

Comment: @EmbeddedDesign Have you used my two-liner? It should work, since it reads the first four bytes as an integer in native byte order.

Comment: In my first post I did throw out `cout << "Start" << endl;` during code cleanup of the C++ code for post. Due to your help with starting the browser from command line, I did find that problem. The first 4 letters "Star" were interpreted as the message length and result in the error `Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 1819042115 bytes long.` and that results into the disconnect. Deleting this line solved the problem. Maybe you can post that as an second answer or add it to your answer as I found it only with your help?

Comment: Yes I'm using your two-liner although in my application I'm sending only max. 10 bytes at once so 255 byte are more that sufficient, but you have the correct solution.